# Custom number format that takes number input and outputs related text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I have a table *T1* where a number matches a name, basically the look-up table. In another table *T2* I want to input just the number, and Excel should fill in the corresponding name in the same cell. The number should be replaced by the name in *T2*.

One way to do this is by using the well known combination of INDEX and MATCH functions. However, this requires a helper column for the number to type in. This is my fallback solution.

**Is it possible to solve this with a custom number format?**

Comment: To fix this issue Excel has many methods, but let me ask, what is the role of Custom Number Format to get Name for the Number? And what Number Format you are suppose to use for the exercise?

Comment: @RajeshS One example of an existing custom format would be this: _"section 1";"section 2";"section 3"_, where the sections correspond to positive values, negative values, and zero or text values respectively. So if I type a positive number, the number changes to whatever is between the double quotes of _section 1_. I thought this might be customizable in some way.

Comment: NO,, whether the number is Positive or Negative it's number but if One value is Number and other is Text then TYPE is different. "Custom Number Format" is suppose, One Number has NUMBER format like is 2 and other is $ 2.00 has currency Format, so both has different "Number Formats" even though both are NUMBERS.

Comment: And yes,, it is possible to extract Name from Table1, if both Numbers have same NUMBER FORMAT. Better you upload the sample data, I'll solve the issue.

Comment: @RajeshS It is a number, positive, negative or zero, yes. But with the custom number format Excel displays text, exactly the text I put into double quotes. So if I create a format _"house";"mountain";"valley"_, then typing a positive number will result in the cell displaying _house_.

Comment: Due to confidentiality reasons I am afraid I can not upload the sample data. I think there is no need to, I know how to achieve my goal in other ways. I was just curious if it was possible with a custom number format.

Comment: To test the Positive number you can simply try if(D1>=0,"POSITIVE","NEGATIVE") so the if(D1>=0,vlookup(D1,A1:B10,2,false), will extract Name from T1 by match D1 in A1:A10.

Comment: @RajeshS Thanks for your help. I discarded the number format approach and solved it with the combination of INDEX and MATCh functions.

Comment: It is possible with a *VBA* macro.  Is this approach acceptable??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Rather not, a macro raises all kinds of problems on other fronts in my case.

Comment: To do this with custom formats, **NOT** using VBA, you would have to create each format manually.  You must also keep in mind that there is a limit to the number of custom formats in a workbook.  It can be a large number, but the limit is there.  I suggest you either use your backup plan, or use a VBA solution (e.g an event triggered macro to do the replacement).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I did not know about the limit of custom formats, thank you for that. Other than that I used the backup plan.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a manual way to achieve your desired result.
If you enter a number in a cell, you can always force the display of given text.  For example if we want a cell to display *Dog* when a number is entered, we apply a custom number format of:

**"Dog";;;**

[image]

Note the  Formula Bar shows *1*, but the cell displays *Dog*

Say our final goal is to take a limited set of cells, say **A1** through **A10** and enter values *1* through *3* and have three different words displayed.  It would be easy to create a macro to detect the values being entered and apply the correct format automatically.  You could do the same thing yourself manually *(but it would be tedious)*

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately doing it manually is not an option either since the purpose of it should be that users only type a number, instead of the whole name.